Возникает ошибка: Refused to execute script from 'test-func.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable
Возникает такая ошибка Refused to execute script from 'https://vlg-t-foss-dckr:7000/static/test-func.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled при попытке запуска js-файла index.html.
Есть проект, который включает в себя бэкенд на Django и фронтенд на React.
Вэб-страница запускается через АПИ в ДЖанго, то есть через view.
Такое представление
class RenderReactClassApiView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    def RenderReact(request, ):
        req_path, *_ = request.path.split(';')
        return render(request, 'index.html')

    class Media:
        js = ('test-func.js', 'static/test-func.js', './static/test-func.js', )

В index.html подключение скрипта выглядит так:
<body>

{% block scripts %}

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="/home/test/app1/backend/templates/test-func.js"></script>

    <script src="{% static 'test-func.js' %}"></script>

{% endblock %}

При переходе к странице АПИ https://localhost:7000/react  в консоли выдаёт ошибку:
Refused to execute script from 'https://localhostr:7000/home/test/app1/backend/templates/test-func.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Возможно, я путь указываю не верно, хотя это абсолютный путь.

Ну и в чем вопрос-то? Консолька же все говорит. MIME-тип корявый, значит сервер криво настроен.

@yar85 Как настроить так, чтобы было не "коряво" и ошибки не было с MIME?

Суть вопроса пишется в вопросе, а не в комментариях к нему. И хорошо бы дополнить эту суть инфой (тоже в вопросе): например, чем у тебя сервятся статические ресурсы... ведь скорее всего не бэк, а именно HTTP сервер формирует заголовки для статики.

@yar85 Вэб-сервер Apache. Но если через WSGI делать, то та же самая ошибка. По "например, чем у тебя сервятся статические ресурсы... ведь скорее всего не бэк, а именно HTTP сервер формирует заголовки для статики." - я не очень разбираюсь в этом - знал бы написал бы сразу. Любые js-файлы и css-файлы определяет с ошибкой. Пути указаны верно - ошибки Not found  не выдаёт.

Хм, странно. И да, похоже что не в апаче дело (у него модуль MIME по-умолчанию понимает .js-файлы т.е. без всяких донастроек). Может все-таки через джанговский сервак сервится статика... уже пробовал такое дописать в конфиг? Вариант конечно тот еще боян, но все-таки...

@yar85 К сожалению, не помог предложенный вариант. Я уже что только не перепробовал. Скорее всего "статик урл некорректно обрабатывается".

Не знаю насколько ответ будет полным и правильным, но мне помогли следующие решения:
если запускать собранный проект на Реакте через Джанго, то нужно указать в index.html описание скрипта так:
{% load static %}
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="{% static 'frontend/main.js' %}"></script>

Если через Апач запускать, то есть Apache2 использовать как вэб-сервер для Джанго, то так:
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static 'frontend/main.js' %}"></script>

и в конфигах сайта Апача нужно указать путь к статике (static) примерно так:
<VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/cert.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/cert.key

        **Alias /static /home/test/ПУТЬ/static
        <Directory /home/test/ПУТЬ/static>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>**


        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ...

Если найду более лучшее решение, потом добавлю.

